# Output of solve in maxima and sage have x on both side

Tags: solver, sage, maxima

I am trying to solve equation

> sqrt(x)==sqrt(20*(1500-x))

in sage and getting the output as given bellow,

> sqrt(x) == sqrt(-20*x + 30000)

Problem in the above solution is that there is x in both side. How can I solve this kind of question sot that I get proper solution. I have tried the same problem in maxima also and getting same answer.

Comment: You are getting the same answer in Maxima because Sage uses Maxima for this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options in Sage with `solve`, and this one seems to help (I assume the answer is okay).

```
sage: solve(sqrt(x)==sqrt(20*(1500-x)),x,to_poly_solve=True)
[x == (10000/7)]
```